# import static org.joox.JOOX.*: - The import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, joox

It's rather a simple problem (I'm a beginner).

I'm using Eclipse.
I just don't know why it won't work to import JOOX.

I browsed and tried changing the JRE/JDK, it didn't help though.

I'd be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the library to your project, have a look [here](http://book2s.com/java/jar/j/joox/download-joox-1.3.0.jar.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options in order to solve this:

1. Download JOOX.jar and add it to your project (drag&drop,copy/paste) and add it to the Build path of your project or
2. Add JOOX maven dependency to pom.xml file

You can find JOOX library [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/joox/1.4.0)

Comment: I added it to Ivy dependency, thanks for the latest link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't added joox-1.1.0.jar or any latest jar for joox . please try to add particluar jar in build path and try i hope it will work.